# Как запретить перерисовку компонента при использовании внутри него глобального состояния из Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

На странице есть 3 компонента: Header, Sidebar и UserTable.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В компоненте Header есть кнопка открытия/закрытия сайдбара (на картинки кнопка рядом с логотипом). При нажатии на кнопку она вернёт true или false, соответственно исходя из этого показателя сайдбар будет либо открываться, либо закрываться. Так, как сайдбар и хедер два разных компонента, я прописал эту логику через Redux. Теперь, появилась необходимость, чтобы UserTable также знал о состоянии сайдбара (открыт он или закрыт). Я, также использовал Redux useSelector внутри компонента UserTable, но заметил, что при каждом изменении состояния сайдбара компонент UserTable перерисовывается. Можно ли избежать этих перерисовок, но заставить следить этот компонент за сайдбаром? Просто сейчас этот компонент простой, но в дальнейшем у него будет гораздо больше логики, поэтому нужно задуматься над оптимизацией. Или я слишком паранойю по этому поводу?

Comment: В чем конкретно будет заключаться "слежение"? Обычно "слежение" так или иначе ведет к изменению внешнего вида, т.е. рендеру компонента.

Comment: Если нажать кнопку закрытия сайдбара, то тогда он уедет в лево за экран и скроется с монитора, чтобы занять пустое пространство сайдбара, таблица растянется влево. Соответственно если сайдбар откроется, то таблица обратно уменьшится

Comment: Для этого не обязательно "следить". Все отработает простым `css`...